# Python sqlite how to query and get an item from generated lists?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to run a query on sqlite and get a list of information. Then I'm planning to use that list to return a specific item in that list. Here is the code:

```
    c = conn.cursor() 
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM general_info WHERE product_name=?", (b,)) 
    add_product_name = c.fetchall()
```

After i run this im getting a list.

```
print(type(add_product_name))

<class 'list'>
```

Lets say the list is:

```
print(add_product_name)

[(apple, banana, cherry)]
```

When I try to get an element in that list

```
item1 = add_product_name[0]
print(item1)
```

it returns:

```
[(apple, banana, cherry)]
```

So, as you can see my list isn't a normal list somehow. Anyone has any idea about what is going on?
I could use a solid documentation about sqlite python and sql queries if you know of any.
Sorry for the messy narration, hope this explains my problem.

Comment: you must do a for x in add_product_name

Comment: Are you certain that you are getting a list and not just a tuple in your last example?

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar, tried that and it returned the whole list at each iteration.

Comment: @IainShelvington im not sure what im getting, but output is the same as my last example. So even if its a tuple wouldnt tup[x] work to get the element?

Comment: wait ..SELECT * FROM general_info WHERE product_name=  this only should give me 1 row??

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar yes it gives one row of data(since there are no duplicates), each item belongs to a different column in that row.

Comment: fetchone() will return you a single result if that is what you are expecting

Answer (score 1):

Solved like this:

```
        var_group = [var1,var2,var3]

        c = conn.cursor() 
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM general_info WHERE product_name=?", (b,)) 
        add_product_name = c.fetchone()

        for x in add_product_name 
           var_group[i] = x
           i += 1
```

Tho it didn't make it any simpler it was a solution. I wish there was a more straight forward way.

My thanks to @GiovaniSalazar and @Iain Shelvington.

Comment: take this reference in which case to use fetchone or  fetchall https://pynative.com/python-cursor-fetchall-fetchmany-fetchone-to-read-rows-from-table/